# Can a std::back_insert_iterator be used on a std::ostream?

Tags: c++, boost, stl, iterator, iostream

As per the title question.

I assume that the answer is "No, because the `std::back_insert_iterator` object calls `push_back()` on the container."

If the answer is in fact no, then is there any template class iterator that I can use in my template function to both append to a `std::string`, append to a `std::vector<char>`, and write to an `std::ostream`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what [`std::ostream_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/ostream_iterator) is for:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    char c[] = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' };

    std::vector<char> v;
    std::string s;

    std::copy(c, c+4, std::back_inserter(v));
    std::copy(c, c+4, std::back_inserter(s));
    std::copy(c, c+4, std::ostream_iterator<char>(std::cout));
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6081e2d6d0e55f1d)

Comment: Thank you. I adjusted my function so that instead of accepting a `std::back_insert_iterator<Container>` as the fourth argument (an instantiation using the type of the previous template parameter), the fourth argument is now parameterised to be an `OutputIterator`. Many thanks for the quick help.

Comment: @user1420752 If this solved your question please accept by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer.